# How do I center align a div's content with content elements floated towards the left?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a simple image gallery where the gallery items are placed in a div. But since the items are floated left, they don't center align overall when I add **text-align: center;** to the parent div. (I'm using Bootstrap 3 and parent div is **panel-body**. The contents lie in panel-body.)

[image: Content Floating Left:]

CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .image-box {
        float: left;
    }

    .image-box img {
        width: 128px;
        height: 128px;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
        <h3 class="panel-title">GALLERY</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="image-box">
            <img src="member-icon.png">
            <P class="caption">Image Description</P>
        </div>
        <div class="image-box">
            <img src="member-icon.png">
            <P class="caption">Image Description</P>
        </div>
        <div class="image-box">
            <img src="member-icon.png">
            <P class="caption">Image Description</P>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**text-align: center;** will not work when use floating. use inline block.

Please see code below

```css
.panel-body {
    text-align: center;
}
.image-box {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -4px;
}
.image-box img {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
        <h3 class="panel-title">GALLERY</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="image-box">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
            <P class="caption">Image Description</P>
        </div>
        <div class="image-box">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
            <P class="caption">Image Description</P>
        </div>
        <div class="image-box">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
            <P class="caption">Image Description</P>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a live demo](http://codepen.io/morshed/pen/EyxwEG)

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

HTML file:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading text-center">
    <h3 class="panel-title">GALLERY</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-xs-offset-3">
    <div class="image-box">
        <img src="member-icon.png">
        <p class="caption">Image Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-box">
        <img src="member-icon.png">
        <p class="caption">Image Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-box">
        <img src="member-icon.png">
        <p class="caption">Image Description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS file:

```
 .image-box {
    float: left;
  }

.image-box img {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    padding:15px;
   }
```

See Demo: [Div content center in panel body](http://www.bootply.com/dePfQtH3pS)

Comment: Thanks. I can see why that would seem to work, but it's definitely not the perfect solution.